# ReleaseComboBox

Tags: rally

Having an issue getting the selected value from the ReleaseComboBox.

I am trying to get this value to use as a filter, so my _onChange event looks something like this:

```
                 _onReleaseComboboxChanged: function () {
                var config = {
                    storeConfig: {
                            filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'ScheduleState', 
                                value: 'Defined'
                            },
                            {
                                property: 'Release.Name',
                                value: this.iterationCombobox.rawValue 

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                };

                this.cardBoard.refresh(config);
            },
```

So this works great most of the time, EXCEPT the combobox is truncating the longer release names, so if your release is named Release 2 - Cool new feature to production, the rawValue = something like "Release 2 - Cool new feature to...".  Obviously, this makes my query return 0 records...

I have looked all through the object in debug, checked docs, I am just not seeing it.

Surely I am missing something here, i checked comboBox to see if there is a truncate property, but dont see that either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to get the currently selected record using the getRecord() method.

```
var selectedIteration = this.iterationCombobox.getRecord();
var iterationName = selectedIteration.get('Name');
```